# PHP a custom SUPERGLOBAL array question

Tags: php, arrays, superglobals

I was reading around, and I know it might be impossible to accomplish as I wished it would be but I am hoping there is a way, so here goes..

I have ID's of users and I have a count for each.
I would like to be able to store those values in machine memory, and update the DB only once in a while, but absolutley not constantly.
The page is being accessed from many users of course, and I want the array to stay relevant for each user, and update as necessary. (That's another reason I don't want to use the DB. Updates take time with indexed columns, right?)

an array such as :
$my_superglobal_arr = ('1'=>304,'2'=>763,'6'=>12,'13'=>96);
would have been perfect.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you talking about updating the db during a single request, or between multiple requests?

Try looking up Memcached or Redis and seeing if it fits the bill.

Comment: @zerkms read message body, not title only :P

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: welcome back :-))))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Updates take time with indexed columns, right?

Right. However, it depends. 
I'd strongly suggest you to go for the database first, get **practical experience** with updates and stuff, learn what particular amount of users you can call "many". And only then decide, if you really need your unusual setup, is it really necessary or just imaginary fantasies.

Reading your other questions I only can say that to learn SQL first is a must.

Comment: I completely agree on that! Though, I have bumped into an interesting answer incorporating SESSIONs, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105866/i-want-to-define-a-variable-with-superglobal-scope-in-php . Using a file with the hosts own caching file abilites seems like a descent solution is it not ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to couple `ArrayAccess` with [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.apc.php) caching abilities and employ a `Singleton` pattern.

```
class UserCounter implements ArrayAccess {
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        static $instance;
        if (!$instance) {
            $instance = new self;
        }
        return $instance;
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {
        apc_store(__CLASS__.$offset, $value);
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return !!apc_fetch(__CLASS__.$offset);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        apc_delete(__CLASS__.$offset);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) 
    {
        return apc_fetch(__CLASS__.$offset);
    }

    private function __construct() {}
    private function __clone() {}
    private function __wakeup() {}
}
```

Usage:

```
$user_counter = UserCounter::getInstance();
$user_counter[1] = $user_counter[1] + 1;
var_dump($user_counter[1]);
```

Output on the first request:

```
int(1)
```

On the second:

```
int(2)
```

When you need to save these counters in a database:

```
$user_counter = UserCounter::getInstance();
foreach ($users as $user_id) {
   store_counter_in_db($user_id, $user_counter[$user_id]);
}
```

Note: [there is a bug](http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16814) which may prevent you from incrementing a single counter during single request in certain versions of APC. Incrementing in subsequent requests is not a problem, as far a I can tell.

Comment: Great comment, I never heard about APC, and it's good to know it's there, though it doesn't seem to be part of php, and some servers don't have it or won't allow me to install it. Please check my comment on @Col. Shrapnel and the link, does that seem like a descent approach ? Thanks for the code!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something PHP offers natively. You're best bet is to store the data in a memory based key/value store. PHP natively supports [memcached](http://memcached.org/) which most hosts offer. You can also take a look at [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and [Redis](http://redis.io/)

Comment: Thanks for Memcache, MongoDB and Redis! I was looking for a php inherent solution though. Thanks again

Comment: That's the problem. There isn't a PHP solution that doesn't involve a non-native extension or some other service. Each PHP request is executed within it's own space. Anything from one request to another is lost. The only way to save this state is to store it in a file, database, or send it to another service for this job (memcached, other databases). Since you want it in memory, using a file or PHP's regular session handling (which is file based - unless you've changed the session handling) wont work. I agree with other comments that you should evaluate why it isn't working with SQL first.