# need to have a shared memory array between PHP scripts

Tags: php

So I have this **a.php** file that is doing a **SELECT X FROM Y WHERE Z**.
**a.php** is called many times by users.
I would like to keep track of the rows that have been served, so I'd like to keep a counter for each row.

The question I am asking is how can I keep track of these counters? Of course I can store them in the DB, but this would mean that many updates would have to take place on the server side for each user and updates on indexed columns consume time.

Another option I thought would be interesting was proposed on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105866/i-want-to-define-a-variable-with-superglobal-scope-in-php)
What I think is that using a server file (the session points to a local file on the server) would be interesting solution, but what is two or more users read the file about the same time? 
They would read the counter 7 for row #23, and then would write 8 back to the file. So if for example it were 3 users together, it means the counter is now 3-1 digits lagging behind. Thus instead of being 10 (7+3) it is only 7+2 = 9.

Your ideas?

Comment: Use memcache or APC to store these values

Comment: The answer will depend on whether these counter values need to persist.  If they should never be reset, storing them in persistent storage (such as a database) will be necessary.

Comment: Also depends on whether your server/host has APC or memcache installed. If not, do you have sufficient privileges to have either one installed?

Comment: If file based sessions are used, it will use advisory locking to make sure only one PHP script can read / write it.

Comment: @cdhowie, if you mean by persistent that they should never be reset then no, once in a while I would like to flush them into the DB, resetting their values. I just don't want the DB to go through updating for every single counter.

Comment: @Ted Have you profiled to determine if using a database server to track these values will be a bottleneck?

Comment: @cdhowie - no. I agree that it is advisable to test beforehand, but as I expect more and more users to use my server, it will be a matter of time until this is a bottleneck. I would just like to avoid having a possible bottleneck beforehand as I won't be able to deal with the server in the coming time.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with a file you will need to manage locks. If you already have a database I'd stick with that unless you really are running into performance problems there. If that's the case you probably don't want to be writing to disk at all and look for an in-memory solution.